# Update the parent array by checking its property: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, mapping, nested-lists

I am having an deeply nested array of objects `arr1` with certain properties, and given another array `arr2` as input,  the corresponding names in these needs to be compared and get the values and append it to one of the array.  In case name is not present in `arr2` then set to the default config, that is `{ val1: false, val2: false, applyToChildren: false }`  in case its parent `applyToChildren` is set to `false`. If its set to true, then copy its parents config to the result.

The structure looks like,

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com",
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
        children: [
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1",
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
    children: []
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com",
    val1: false,
    val2: false,
    applyToChildren: true
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
    val1: true,
    val2: true,
    applyToChildren: true
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
    val1: true,
    val2: false,
    applyToChildren: true
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
    val1: false,
    val2: false,
    applyToChildren: true
  }
];
```

Output should look like,

```
const output = [
  {
    name: "internalcorp.com",
    config: {
      val1: false,
      val2: false,
      applyToChildren: true
    },
    children: [
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
        config: {
          val1: true,
          val2: true,
          applyToChildren: true
        },
        children: [
          {
            name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1",
            children: [],
            config: {
              val1: true,
              val2: true,
              applyToChildren: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
        children: [],
        config: {
          val1: true,
          val2: false,
          applyToChildren: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
    children: [],
    config: {
      val1: false,
      val2: false,
      applyToChildren: true
    }
  }
];
```

Here `internalcorp.com.grandchild2` is not present in arr2 and since its parents `applyToChildren` is `true`, I am copying its config to the result

Code that I tried

```
const addConfig = (items) =>
  items.map(item => {
    const { val1, val2, applyToChildren } = arr2.find(p => p.name === item.name);
    return {
      ...item,
      config: {
        val1,
        val2,
        applyToChildren
      },
      children: addConfig(item.children)
    };
  });

const result = addConfig(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following provided solution uses a recursive [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach. It in addition utilizes the so often forgotten [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) parameter which can be provided as `map`'s 2nd argument where `thisArg` then gets provided as the callback's (the mapping function's) `this` context.

The solution also transforms the child-item `config` array into an object which gets used for easier item-specific config-lookups based on an item's `name`. And in order to pass down a parent specific configuration deeper into the recursion, the bound config data is provided as `{lookup, config}` where `lookup` holds the entire configuration data and `config` holds a reference of the most recent parent item's configuration.

```js
function recursivelyAggregateChildItemFromBoundConfigData(item) {
  const { lookup, config: parentConfig } = this;
  const { name, children = [] } = item;
  const config = { ...(lookup[name] ?? parentConfig) };
  // { ...{} } decouples any direct `config` reference.
  return {
    name,
    config,
    children: children.map(
      recursivelyAggregateChildItemFromBoundConfigData,
      { lookup, config }
    ),
  };
}

const nestedData = [{
  name: "internalcorp.com",
  children: [{
    name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
    children: [{
      name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1",
      children: [],
    }],
  }, {
    name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
    children: [],
  }],
}, {
  name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
  children: []
}];

const itemConfigList = [{
  name: "internalcorp.com",
  val1: false,
  val2: false,
  applyToChildren: true
}, {
  name: "internalcorp.com.child1",
  val1: true,
  val2: true,
  applyToChildren: true
}, {
  name: "internalcorp.com.child2",
  val1: true,
  val2: false,
  applyToChildren: true
}, {
  name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",
  val1: false,
  val2: false,
  applyToChildren: true
}];

console.log(
  'lookup table/index/map ...',
  Object.fromEntries(
    itemConfigList.map(({ name:key, ...value }) => [key, value])
  )
);
console.log(
  'recursively mapped nested data ...',
  nestedData.map(recursivelyAggregateChildItemFromBoundConfigData, {
    lookup: Object.fromEntries(
      itemConfigList.map(({ name:key, ...value }) => [key, value])
    ),
    config: null,
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: May I know, where this default config is set incase no match is found ?

Comment: line 4 ... `(lookup[name] ?? parentConfig)` where `parentConfig` will equal `lookup[name]` from the same line but from an earlier parent recursion. And if nothing matches at all (right from the beginning), this value will equal `null` as provided with the initial `map` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a simple `Array.forEach`

**Logic.**

- Loop through each object in `arr1`
- Check for each object in `arr1`, if a value with same `name` exist in `arr2`.
- If exist update the `config` of that node.
- If not check if its parent has `applyToChildren` set.
- If set use the config from parent
- Else use the default config
- I have used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1))` as the paramanter, to ensure that deep copy is preformed

**Worling Fiddle**

```js
const arr1 = [{name: "internalcorp.com", children: [{name: "internalcorp.com.child1",children: [ { name: "internalcorp.com.grandchild1", children: [] } ]},{name: "internalcorp.com.child2",children: []}]},{name: "internalcorpwebsite.com",children: []}];

const arr2 = [{ name: "internalcorp.com", val1: false, val2: false, applyToChildren: true },{ name: "internalcorp.com.child1", val1: true, val2: true, applyToChildren: true },{ name: "internalcorp.com.child2", val1: true, val2: false, applyToChildren: true },{ name: "internalcorpwebsite.com", val1: false, val2: false, applyToChildren: true }];

const defaultConfig = { val1: false, val2: false, applyToChildren: false };

const addConfig = (items, parentNode) => {
  items.forEach((node) => {
    const valueNode = arr2.find(value => value.name === node.name);
    if(valueNode) {
      const { name, ...config } = valueNode;
      node.config = config;
    } else {
      if (parentNode && parentNode.config && parentNode.config.applyToChildren) {
        node.config = parentNode.config;
      } else {
        node.config = defaultConfig;
      }
    }
    if(node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
      node.children.forEach(child => addConfig(node.children, node))
    }
  })
  return items;
}

const result = addConfig(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1)), null);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Maybe one considers another approach than within each iteration doing another `find` based iteration. And even though one has to use a recursive approach, the transformation task itself is pure mapping. Why not using then a recursive `map` instead of a recursive `forEach` (which also would make `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr1))` obsolete)?